# UICollectionViewController embed in UIContainerView - How to pass the data to the parent?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uicollectionview, uicontainerview

My setup looks like this:

I have a `UIViewController` with differnt elements on top of it including one `UIContainerView`. This container has a `UICollectionView` with 9 `UICollectionViewCell` embed in it. All of these cells have one `UILabel` on it. The cells are all selectable. So what I basically did is created a multi selection element. My question is, how to pass the selected cells (best as NSArray with the strings of all selected elements) to the parent, the `UIViewController`?

What I did so far is create an `IBOutlet` to the container in the top `UIViewController`:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MultiSelectionContainerView *multiSelectionCV;
```

I'd like to be able to acces the array of selected cells like this:

```
NSArray* selectedCells = [_multiSelectionCV getSelection];
```

How do I best do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your `MultiSelectionContainerView` has a `UICollectionView` ember in it , In your `MultiSelectionContainerView`:

```
 - (NSArray *)getSelection{
    NSMutableArray *selectedItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in [self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems]){
        YourCollectionViewCell *cell = [self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [selectedItems addObject:cell.label.text];
    }
    return selectedItems;
}
```

**EDIT:**

You have to pass these layers level by level, like `UIViewController` holds `MultiSelectionContainerView` as property,`MultiSelectionContainerView` holds `MultiSelectionViewController`,and you implement my answer in MultiSelectionViewController.then you can access it via

```
 [self. multiSelectionCV.multiSelectionVC getSelection]
```

Comment: How can I access the `UIViewController` from the overlying `UIContainerView`? Thanks for your answer so far!

Comment: Is this relation `UIViewController`->`MultiSelectionContainerView`->`UIContainerView` right? I thought you want to access container view in your top ViewController.

Comment: The relation is `UIViewController` -> `UIView` -> `MultiSelectionContainerView` -> `MultiSelectionViewController` -> `MultiSelectionView` -> `MultiSelectionCell`. I can access the `MultiSelectionContainerView` over the outlet from above but I struggle to figure how to access the next layer, the `MultiSelectionViewController`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I established the last missing connection with a prepareForSegue and by calling my getSelection method via the segue.destinationViewController object.